# Date formatting - DD-MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: php, mysql, date, phpmyadmin

MySQL table has 2 columns - startdate and enddate

They hold dates in this format: 22-01-2016

When I was prototyping, I used MediumText.

Now, I want to switch to Date format. The default date format in PHPMyAdmin is YYYY-MM-DD

If I switch the columns to Date, my data turns into 0000-00-00.

Using PHP or MySQL, how do I reformat my data prior to going back into PHPMyAdmin to switch the columns to Date format?

Comment: Do you store `startdate` and `enddate` in DB using VARCHAR or DATE datatype?

Comment: Don't use text formats for storing dates in arbitrary formats..... store dates in date datatypes in the first place; but MySQL can't simply let you change that column to a date, because the content of the column as a varchar isn't a recognised date format

Comment: When prototyping - needed something quick and dirty. Now, I need to optimise the application.

Comment: Perhaps start by updating all the data in your existing mediumtext to a YYYY-MM-DD format, and then changing the datatype as a second step

Comment: Better insert into another field that is properly typed, and the drop the varchar field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use string to date function to update columns data before changing its structure

```
UPDATE table SET dateColumn = STR_TO_DATE(dateColumn, '%d-%m-%Y');
```

It will convert DD-MM-YYYY formatted dates to YYYY-MM-DD. After that you can just change structure of column to `DATE`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most reliable way would be to split up the dates and rearrange them the other way round:

```
$parts = explode('-', $olddate);
$newdate = sprintf('%04d-%02d-%02d', $parts[2], $parts[1], $parts[0]);
```